# Standard way to handle style in React component

Tags: reactjs

All:

I am pretty new to React, I wonder if anyone can give me some tutoirals about how to handle style. I am from AngularJS jQuery areas which use stylesheet and manipulate different class names in the DOM, but I do not if this is the way it is supposed to work in React?

Thanks

Comment: Either use class names (via `className` property) or [css-modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)

Comment: @zerkms Thanks, so I can do it in same way in AngularJS?

Comment: Yep ......................

Comment: @zerkms Thanks. That seems ease me a lot